# incorect svg convert with image magick php

Tags: php, svg, imagemagick, imagick

I have problem with convert svg

My sctipn generate svg image

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="802" width="744" version="1.1">
    <desc>Created with Rapha&#xEB;l</desc>
    <defs>
        <mask id="fademask" x="0" y="0" width="744" height="802">
            <image xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAMSURBVBhXY2BgYAAAAAQAAVzN/2kAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" preserveAspectRatio="none" height="804" width="1" y="0" x="745"/>
            <image xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAe0AAAGTCAIAAACK/t0dAAAKKUlEQVR4nO3YwXLbuhIEUOX9/z/nLuByKnqKJZIgMA2cs/LSBYwazXk8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA9vJr9j8AB/z+/bv98euX0YUvfgzE+A7xRpRD45dAhqcQb0Q5PB6P/83+BwC4RJ0hwMsy3qjk4DdAdT+EeCPK2ZwfAKW9DfFGlLMz+3GAbFoMdX1YxhuVnG0ZfYo6FOKNKGdP5p6KToR4I8rZkP04QDblhXJOl/FGJWc3Jp5aLoZ4I8rZinGnkC4h3ohy9mE/DpBNZ6GKjmW8UcnZhEGnhO4h3ohydmDKme+mEG9EOcuzHwfIpqow2a1lvFHJWZv5ZqYBId6IchZmuJlmWIg3opxV2Y8DZNNQmGNwGW9UcpZkrJlgSog3opz1mGlGmxjijShnMfbjANkUE4aaXsYblZyVmGbGKRLijShnGUaZQUqFeCPKWYP9OEA2fYQRCpbxRiVnAYaY25UN8UaUk84Ec6/iId6IcqLZjwNkU0O4UUQZb1Rycpld7hIU4o0oJ5TB5RZxId6IchLZjwNk0z7oL7SMNyo5cYwsnUWHeCPKyWJe6WmBEG9EOUHsxwGyKR10s0wZb1RyUphU+lgsxBtRTgRjSgdLhngjyqnPfhwgm67BVQuX8UYlpzgDyiXLh3gjyqnMdHLeJiHeiHLKsh8HyKZicNJWZbxRyanJXHLGhiHeiHIKMpQctm2IN6KcauzHAbJpFhyzeRlvVHJKMY4cIMS/iXLqMIt8Sog/EeUUYT8OkE2h4CPK+EsqORWYQt4T4j8Q5UxnBHlDiL8lypnLfhwgmx7BT5TxD6nkTGT4+CchfogoZxaTx2tC/ARRzhT24wDZ1AdeUMZPU8kZz8zxTIhfJMoZzMDxFyHehShnJPtxgGxaA38o4x2p5Axj1PgixLsT5Yxhzng8hPhtRDkD2I8DZFuzLGiXEMoXzAkLHpkQh2ii/Ch7FYBschwg25rfL1YrEMpS5QR9HCDbsk+fSg5xlPFzVj41UQ5BhPhp9ioA2RZ/AFVyiKCMX7H+2YlyKE6IX7T+XsWIAGtbP8eByjSt63Y5QdsVKEiId7FLHzcuwKp2yXGgGu2ql73O0XYFihDiHe3Vx40OsJ69chyoQKPqa8fTtF2BiYR4dzv2cWMErGTHHAdm0aLusO+Z2q7AYEL8JlsfqyiHYYT4fexVALLt/kKq5DCAMn4rhyvK4V5C/G72KgDZvJOPh0oOt1HGB3DEX0Q5dCfEx7BXAcjmtfxDJYeOlPFhHPRfRDl0IcRHslcByObNfKaSw0XK+GCO+wVRDqcJ8fHsVQCyeTlfU8nhBGV8Cof+T6IcDhHis9irAGTzfv5EJYcPKeMTOfo3RDm8JcTnslcByOYVfU8lhx8o49O5gI+IcnhJiFdgrwKQzVv6KZUcnijjRbiGA0Q5fBPiddirAGTzoh6jksNDGS/GZRwmytmcEK/GXgUgm3f1DJWcbSnjBbmSk0Q5GxLiNdmrAGTzup6nkrMVZbwsF3OJKGcTQrwyexWAbN7Yq1RylqeMF+d6OhDlLEyI12evApDNS9uHSs6SlPEILqkbUc5ihHgKexWAbN7bnlRylqGMB3FVnYlyFiDEs9irAGTz6vankhNNGY/jwm4hygklxBPZqwBk8/beRSUnjjIeyrXdSJQTRIjnslcByOYFvpdKTgRlPJrLu50opzghns5eBSCbd3gElZyylPEFuMJBRDkFCfE12KsAZJPjANl8VY1gqUJZVisLcIW3E+IUJ8rT2asAZPMO30sZJ4JKHs3l3UiIE0SU57JXAcjmBb6LMk4clTyUa7uFECeUKE9krwKQzdvbnzJONJU8jgvrTIizAFGexV4FIJtXtydlnGWo5EFcVTdCnMWI8hT2KgDZvLd9KOMsSSWP4JI6EOIsTJTXZ68CkM1Le5UyzvJU8uJczyVCnE2I8srsVYD3VJbK5Ph5JhuowLfSSUKcDdmu1KSPA59SX2qS42eYZqAOX0mHCXE2Z7tSjfs4RojDQ5QXY68CkM2jeoAyDt9U8jrcxKeEODwR5UXYqwBk85x+RBmHl1TyCtzBe0IcfiDKp7NXAcjmIX1DGYe3VPK5nP5PhDh8SJRPZK8CkM0T+k/KOByiks/i3F8T4nCCKJ/CXgUgm8fzBWUcTlPJx3Piz4Q4XCTKB7NXAcjm2fyLMg5dqOQjOes/hDh0JMqHsVcBbqEYDSPHv5g5IJQPn8dDiMNtbFcG0MeBGylJA8hxcwZk2/2TR4jDALYrt9r6cIU4DCPK72OvApBt3xdSGYfBVPKbbHqsQhymEOV3sFcByLbj26iMw0QqeXfbHagQh+lEeV/2KgDZ9noVlXEoQiXvaKOjFOJQiijvxV4FINsu76EyDgWp5F1scYhCHMoS5dfZqwBkW/8lVMahOJX8osWPT4hDBFF+hb0KQLaV30BlHIKo5Kcte3BCHOKI8nPsVYAq1K9z1sxx0wDsY8GvGCEO0WxXjlqzjwPsQ44DZFvz+8VqBUJZqpzgyHg8vHy3kUoMYK8CkE1Z4ItK3p0yzhjmjD9EeUdCnGGMGn8R5V0IcUayHwfIpjXwTCW/SBlnMAPHC6L8NCHOeGaO10T5CUKcKezHAbKpD/yTSn6IMs4sJo+fiPIPCXEmMny8IcrfEuLMZT8OkE2P4D2V/AfKONMZQT4iyl8S4lRgCvmUKH8ixCnCfhwgm0LBASr5N2WcOswix4jyhxCnGOPIYZtHuRCnGvtxgGyaBWdsW8mVcQoylJy0YZQLcWoyl5y3VZQLccqyHwfIpmJwySaVXBmnMtPJVctHuRCnOANKBwtHuRCnPvtxgGy6Bn0sWcmVcSIYU7pZLMqFOClMKj0tE+VCnCD24wDZlA46W6CSK+NkMa/0Fx3lQpw4RpZbhEa5ECeR/ThANu2Du8RVcmWcUAaXGwVFuRAnl9nlXhFRLsSJZj8OkE0N4XbFK7kyTjoTzAhlo1yIswBDzCAFo1yIswb7cYBs+gjjlKrkyjjLMMoMVSTKhTgrMc2MNj3KhTiLsR8HyKaYMMHESq6Msx4zzRxTolyIsyRjzTSDo1yIsyr7cYBsGgozDavkyjgLM9xMNiDKhThrM9/Md2uUC3GWZz8OkE1VoYSbKrkyzg5MOVV0j3IhziYMOoV0jHIhzj7sxwGy6SzU0qWSK+NsxbhTzsUoF+LsxsRT0ekoF+JsyH4cIJvyQlEnKrkyzp7MPXUdinIhzraMPqV9GOVCnJ3ZjwNk02Ko7m0lV8bZnB8AAX6IciEOfgNkeBnlQhwe9uMA6dQZYjxVcmUcGr8EknxHuRAHAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgP/zHy+xj7Em7Wk1AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" preserveAspectRatio="none" height="802" width="744" y="1" x="1"/>
            <image xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAMSURBVBhXY2BgYAAAAAQAAVzN/2kAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" preserveAspectRatio="none" height="804" width="1" y="0" x="0"/>
            <image xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAMSURBVBhXY2BgYAAAAAQAAVzN/2kAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" preserveAspectRatio="none" height="1" width="744" y="0" x="1"/>
            <image xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAMSURBVBhXY2BgYAAAAAQAAVzN/2kAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" preserveAspectRatio="none" height="1" width="744" y="803" x="1"/>
        </mask>
    </defs>
    <g mask="url(#fademask)">
        <image xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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" preserveAspectRatio="none" height="403" width="493" y="113" x="145"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Code is correct.

Code for convert

```
$imagick = new Imagick(); 
$imagick->readImageBlob($data); 
$imagick->setImageFormat("pdf");

echo $imagick;
```

if I use host with ImageMagick 6.5.6-10, convert is ok (left - pdf, right - svg)
http://clip2net.com/s/2LO2O

if I use ImageMagick 6.8.2, very bad convert
http://clip2net.com/s/2LO1p

Please, help

Comment: Ugh. This might be a case for ImageMagick's bug tracker / support resources unless someone can spot something off in the SVG

Comment: does imagick natively handle pdf, or does it just pass things off to ghostscript?

Comment: Pekka, no, I use 2 different host (on unix and windows). with 6.8.2 not work. I tried save to png or jpg. Not work.

Marc B, I use Raphael (js) for create image (svg), and last need convert this image to pdf

I think that error read from svg. If read in 682 and write in svg, tag 'mask' not write.